# Network Manager won't connect to open (non-encrypted) Wi-Fi access point

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, encryption

How do I instruct Network Manager to connect to a Wi-Fi access point with no encryption using an already-defined Wi-Fi connection?

I have tried:

```
nmcli connection modify "${CONNECTION}" \
802-11-wireless-security.key_mgmt none \
802-11-wireless-ssid "${SSID}" \
802-11-wireless-security.psk ""
```

The error I receive is:

```
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'TESTAP'.
Warning: password for '802-11-wireless-security.wep-key0' not given in 'passwd-file' and nmcli cannot ask without '--ask' option.
```

It is interesting that it mentions WEP... I never touched any settings with WEP.